# moving elements in arraylist java

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

I have the following array list:

```
arrList = {"A", "2b", "3c", "4x", "5y", "6k", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"}
```

and I want to move the elemnents around so it becomes:

```
arrList = {"A", "3c", "4x", "5y", "6k", "2b", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "13", "14", "15", "16", "12", "17", "18", "19", "20"}
```

notice the item in the: 
2nd position have moved to the 6th position.
12th position have moved to 16th position

Can anyone show me how to achieve this using for loop? or is there a better way?

If my list is dynamic and keeps growing I want the same pattern to continue so that the item in:

22nd position will move to 26th position

Comment: Removing the element from the list and inserting it at the position you want is the easiest way in terms of lines of code. (I *know* I answered this question yesterday too).

Comment: Try `Collections.swap(arrList, 2,6)` and so on.

Comment: Determining when you need to swap, can be achieved by using modulo (%). We're not writing the code for you here, so you should read up about modulo here http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php

Comment: is there any specific number or sequence  by using which increment is to be done to swap the position of the numbers ?

Comment: Your patterns shows the elements should shift 4 positions to right so just place last 4 elements at the start your code is done

Comment: "If my list is dynamic and keeps growing" That is irrelevant to the problem here. As is clearly documented in the [`ArrayList` Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html): "**Note that this implementation is not synchronized**. If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally.". As such, your "growing" and your "moving" **must** happen mutually exclusively for either to be correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In terms of lines of code, it is easiest simply to remove the element from the list and reinsert it at the new position:

```
list.add(toPos, list.remove(fromPos));
```

However, this isn't necessarily the most efficient way to do it, since it requires all of the elements in the array list to be shifted down by the remove, and shifted up by the insert.

You can do it more efficiently by explicitly shifting all of the elements in-place:

```
Integer fromValue = list.get(fromPos);
int delta = fromPos < toPos ? 1 : -1;
for (int i = fromPos; i != toPos; i += delta) {
  list.set(i, list.get(i + delta));
}
list.set(toPos, fromValue);
```

Comment: Swapping the variables isn't correct, though. If you've asked to move the 6th element to position 2, you don't want to move the 2nd element to position 6. I'm pretty sure that the update will work whether `fromPos<toPos` or not.

Comment: It's better now :)

Answer (score 3):

Simple sample how move one element to another without losing data.

```
public void move(List myList, int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        if (fromPosition < toPosition) {
            myList.add(toPosition, myList.get(fromPosition));
            myList.remove(fromPosition);
        } else {
            myList.add(toPosition, myList.get(fromPosition));
            myList.remove(fromPosition + 1);
        }
    }
```

---

For: `[A][B][C][D][E]`

**Case 1**: move `[A]->[B]` fromPosition 0, toPosition 1, condition where `fromPosition < toPosition`

Step 1: `[A][A*][B][C][D]` moved `[A]` to second position (param toPosition)

Step 2: `[A*][B][C][D]` removed old `[A]` position (param fromPosition)

**Case 2**: move `[C]->[A]` fromPosition 2, toPosition 0, condition where `fromPosition >= toPosition`

Step 1: `[C*][A][B][C][D]` moved `[C]` to first position (param toPosition) - we moved to left, so list is stetched (old [C] position increaced by +1)

Step 2: `[C*][A][B][D]` removed old `[C]` position (param fromPosition)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're basically moving the 2nd element to the 6th position etc. you can do the following:

- remove the second element thus shifting the remaining ones to the left by 1
- readd the element at the required position

This can be done in a single line: `list.add( targetPos, list.remove( sourcePos ) )`.

Of course that still is not as efficient as moving only the part that has to be moved by doing it manually but you'll probably not want to bother with that unless you call it really often or have huge lists.

And, as has been pointed out, you'd have to make sure that `sourcePos < targetPos`.

Comment: Your single line doesn't work if `targetPos > sourcePos`.

Answer (score 0):

Your demand is not verry clear, but to move elements around in array list, use  `Collections.swap(arrayList,2,6);` for example

Comment: Swap isn't the most efficient way to do this, since you basically need to do N swaps to move the element N positions. You can simply use `set(i, get(i + 1))` to move the elements left, and then set the final position to the moved element.

Comment: @AndyTurner `Collections.swap()` does exactly that, have a look at the source.

Comment: Right - but it calls set twice as many times as is necessary for this.

Comment: @AndyTurner no, it calls `set()` exactly twice and `get()` exactly once, just as you commented.

Comment: Right - and you have to call `swap` N times to move an element `N` positions along the array list. So you are calling `set()` `2*N` times, whereas you can do it with just `N` sets instead.

Comment: @AndyTurner ah yes, I misread the question that elements 2 and 6 should be swapped, but actually you'd only have to move one element.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the methods `subList` and `addAll`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList-int-int-
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-

For example

`ArrayList myNewList = new ArrayList();
myNewList.addAll(sourceList.subList(2, 8));
myNewList.addAll(sourceList.subList(0, 1));`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like (considering exactly your requirement):

```
int shiftCount = 4;

if(arrList != null) {
    for (int i = 1; i < arrList.size(); i +=10) {
        if(arrList.size() < i+shiftCount+1) break;
        String tmpObj = arrList.get(i);
        arrList.remove(i);
        arrList.add(i+shiftCount, tmpObj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your comment a bit.

Comment: what about gaps that left after removing elements and the code didnot care about elements in the position of insertion that need to shift to other position before insertion.it would be better to use second arraylist to insert elements as they are deleting elements before with out processing .Please take some time to run your code in your IDE thank you.

Comment: I am not getting what you are saying. Secondly, how did you assume I didn't run my code in my IDE? Thirdly I would really appreciate if you come up with an example that will justify your comment so that I can rectify my code if at all required.

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows every element should shift 4 blocks to right here i just placed last 4 elements at first so that every element shift 4 positions as requested here is my code

```
    String  arrList[] = {"A", "2b", "3c", "4x", "5y", "6k", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"}; 
     String part1[] = new String[arrList.length-4];
     System.arraycopy(arrList, 0, part1,0, arrList.length-4);
     //System.out.println(arrList.length);
     String part2[] = new String[4];       
      System.arraycopy(arrList, arrList.length-4, part2,0, 4);
      System.out.println();
      String[] result = Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(part2), Arrays.stream(part1))
              .toArray(String[]::new);
      System.out.println();
      for(int hj =0 ;hj<result.length;hj++)
      { 
        System.out.print(result[hj]+" ");  
      }
```

Hope you found my code helpful.